# How to bypass a javascript Countdown function using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, greasemonkey, countdown

I want to bypass countdown,flood control function in one forum, but i dont know how to do it..
this is what i found in source.

```
`<br /><br />
  <span class='postcolor' style='padding:10px'>Flood control is enabled on this board, please wait 106 seconds before replying or posting a new topic, <script type='text/javascript'><!--
var countDownInterval=106;
//-->
</script>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src='wait_flood.js'></script></span>
  <br /><br /> `
```

When i opened 
**wait_flood.js**
there was another code

```
//Refresh page script- By Brett Taylor (glutnix@yahoo.com.au)
//Modified by Dynamic Drive for NS4, NS6+
//Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com for this script

//configure refresh interval (in seconds)
//var countDownInterval=180;
//configure width of displayed text, in px (applicable only in NS4)
var c_reloadwidth=200

var countDownTime=countDownInterval+1;
function countDown(){
countDownTime--;
if (countDownTime <=0){
countDownTime=countDownInterval;
clearTimeout(counter)
//window.location.reload()
return
}
if (document.all) //if IE 4+
document.all.countDownText.innerText = countDownTime+" ";
else if (document.getElementById) //else if NS6+
document.getElementById("countDownText").innerHTML=countDownTime+" "
else if (document.layers){ //CHANGE TEXT BELOW TO YOUR OWN
document.c_reload.document.c_reload2.document.write('<a href="javascript:window.location.reload()">refresh</a> in&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="+3"><b id="countDownText">'+countDownTime+'</b></font>seconds')
document.c_reload.document.c_reload2.document.close()
}
counter=setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);
}

function startit(){
if (document.all||document.getElementById) //CHANGE TEXT BELOW TO YOUR OWN
document.write('<a href="javascript:window.location.reload()">refresh</a> in&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="+3"><b id="countDownText">'+countDownTime+'</b></font>seconds')
countDown()
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
startit()
else
window.onload=startit
```

Sorry for bad english,i hope you understand..

Comment: Even if you bypass this on the web page, the server will still block you.  That's not something Greasemonkey can help with.

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is not a script-writing service.  (Re)Read the [FAQ] and post MCVE's when asking questions here.

Comment: is there a way to bypass this countdown?

Comment: You can bypass the countdown (see the linked question), but the server will still reject your new post (most forums). There is no way to get around that.